# When using Advanced Chart from Tradingview, how to understand the chart is loaded?

Tags: tradingview-api

I am trying to use embedded chart widget by TV and I need to know when its loaded via `**onChartReady()**`, which is not working and gives "widget.onChartReady is not a function" error. Here's the code:
`https://codepen.io/jqww/pen/Jjwavey`

So I am really confused what is the problem, I read through docs and copied from there.

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_009af"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   const widget = new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "studies": [
    "STD;RSI"
  ],
  "container_id": "tradingview_009af"
}
  );
  
  widget.onChartReady(() => {
           console.log("The TradingView chart widget is fully loaded and ready!");
});
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js does provide widgetReady instead.
From tv.js:

```
 e.postMessage.get("widgetReady", {}, (function() {
                    var t;
                    for (e._ready = !0, t = e._ready_handlers.length; t--;) e._ready_handlers[t].call(e)
                }))
```

And you can check it by:

```
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div id="tradingview_009af"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       const widget = new TradingView.widget(
      {
      "autosize": true,
      "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "studies": [
        "STD;RSI"
      ],
      "container_id": "tradingview_009af"
    }
      );
      
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    try {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (data.provider === 'TradingView' && data.name === 'widgetReady') {
        console.log("The TradingView chart widget is fully loaded and ready!");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error parsing message:", err);
    }
  });
    });
      </script>
    </div>
```